# How can the Kandorians(Kryptonians) have their powers?

Tags: dc, superman, smallville

We see that in the 9th season of Smallville, both in the first and the ninth episode, the Kandorians - whose genes were laced with blue kryptonite - have powers (example, Alia).

How can they have their powers under a yellow sun?
In the first episode Alia had all the powers of a Kryptonian under a yellow sun even after her cells were laced with blue kryptonite, and in the ninth episode she was seen using super speed under a yellow sun.

Also in the alternate timeline(where Lois went) Major Zod and his men had kryptonian abilities under RED sun but Kal- El did not. Why?
How can this be possible?
How can they have their powers under a yellow sun and red sun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr:** None of this is ever *really* explained in the show.

Alia's powers in *Savior* and *Pandora* in the present time, in particular, are a huge plot hole (in particular, in *Pandora* she seems to *keep* her red-sun-given powers when she follows Lois back to a yellow-sun environment.)

How the red sun gave them their powers appears to be a side-effect of how Blue Krpytonite works; at least, Zod seems very convinced that it will work, enough to spend tons of time and money on the Solar Tower. Why this is true, again, is never explained.

---

The explanation for how Zod got his powers was *very* sketchy, but if I am remembering correctly, it's due to the way blue kryptonite affects Kryptonians. It appears to take away their yellow-sun-given powers by changing their biology to make them appear "native" under yellow radiation, but as a side effect, a *red* sun is no longer normal for them, and has the same effect.

In the comics, IIRC there have been a few different explanations for why Superman has special powers when exposed to a yellow sun. *Smallville* never explains how that works for their particular canon, but the basic idea is that yellow sunlight is absorbed by Kryptonians and is somehow converted into energy that gives them extra powers. This is somehow related to their biology, and their evolution on Krypton (which is heavier/denser than Earth and orbits a red star). Therefore, *all* Kryptonians would automatically have these powers as soon as they came within range of a yellow star.

If we assume that blue krptonite somehow interferes with this process, one possibility is that it changes whatever biochemical process responds to yellow wavelengths to make them do nothing. It's possible, then, that the change causes some *other* wavelength to replace yellow's function. Given that red is the furthest from blue in the actual spectrum, it makes as much sense as anything else that blue krpytonite would interefere with yellow radiation more than red. Beyond that, though, it's all basically hand-waved away as "how it's supposed to work."

None of that explains Alia, though. That's a pretty clear writing mistake that they were hoping we wouldn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

Iirc Clark gave Zod a blood transfusion after he was hurt , zod then passed his blood on to the others .as taken from the episode description ;
"As Zod lay dying, Kal-El confessed that Jor-El's last wish was for him to save Zod. Using a kryptonite needle, Kal-El dripped his blood into Zod's bullet wound. Though Kal-El's blood saved Zod, it also managed to restore Zod's natural Kryptonian abilities. After talking with Kal-El and then he left to deal with a crime, Zod took in the yellow light of the sun and flew off the roof of the Daily Planet"

Comment: so then why did Zod make the sun red in the future alternate timeline.. where Zod and his men had powers but Clark did not???

Comment: That was before the tranfusion .he gets his powers from the transfusion in season 9 episode 15

Comment: Lot of downvoters on this site recently , especially if if the answer given was correct

Comment: you answered for the current timeline which was shown... but the question asks about the alternate timeline, where Lois was.

Comment: To be fair, @adeetya - you only added in the bit about the alternate timeline *after* howler posted his answer.

Comment: @phantom42 the last edit was on Nov. 18 and howler answered/edited his answer on Nov.19.. 

I just offered the bounty today

Comment: @adeetya. your original question did not ask about the alternate timeline. howler answered the original question at 16:35 on 11/18. According to the revision history, you didn't add the part about the alternate timeline until almost 45 minutes later. howler *did* edit his answer after that, expanding his answer. it's possible that he didn't see the update to your original question.

Comment: I mentioned "in the 9th episode", where we see all of lois' memories i.e. the alternate timeline. Therefore it was mentioned before the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing when Jor El laced the orb with blue K he altered the biology of the kandorians in such a way that the red sun now gives them powers while the yellow sun takes away their powers.